# Alternative ways to calculate the determinant of a matrix in R

Tags: r, determinants

So it is a mathematical fact that if the determinant of a matrix is equal to zero, then the matrix must be singular (not invertible).  Now, the problem I am running into is that when I calculate the determinant of my matrix it is equal to zero, however, when I calculate the inverse it exist.  I think it has to do with the way R calculates determinants that the two are not agreeing.  Here is the code that I am trying (I wont print the results of solve because the matrix is 100 x 100).

```
> Rinv = solve(R)
> 
> det(R)
[1] 0
> 
> #Using a Cholesky Factorization
> L = chol(R)
> Q = t(L)
> 
> det(L)*det(Q)
[1] 0
```

Comment: Probably a floating point issue (not printing to full decimal value.). Try `det(R) == 0L`

Answer (score 9):

For large matrices the determinant can be too large or too small and overflow the `double` precision.
The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues: for instance, if they are all .0001, your matrix is invertible, but the determinant is `1e-400`, which is too small, and can only be represented as 0.

You can look at the logarithm of the determinant instead,

```
determinant(R, logarithm=TRUE)
```

or, directly, the eigenvalues

```
eigen(R, only.values=TRUE)
```